# make div the size of its contents

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div the size of its contents, but I'm dealing with a ghost line. Can someone give it a look?

```
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        div#holder {
            background-color: blue;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        canvas {
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: gray;
        }


    <div id="holder">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xjmz6n68/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The small gap is because the container is an inline element and there is space reserved for descender elements in a font (e.g. j, g, y). Remove it easily by adding vertical-align:top to the canvas rules:

```
canvas {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: gray;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xjmz6n68/2/)**

or set the font-size to zero on the div:

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/229yy5o4/)**

or float the canvas:

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xn84wm78/)**

Answer (score 1):

There are three options I found already:

add `display:block;` to `canvas`

add `vertical-align:top;` to `canvas`

set `display:inline-flex;` to your `div#holder`

Answer (score 0):

By default, a canvas is rendered inline, like a letter so you can use these solutions:

- `display:block` to `canvas`
- `vertical-align: bottom;` to canvas
- `float: left;` to canvas
- `line-height: 0;` to `div#holder`

.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/xjmz6n68/1/)

Answer (score 0):

give your `#holder` the CSS `line-height: 0;`

Since you're using `inline`, a text-like line-height is applied.

https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/cm4r6k7p/

Answer (score 0):

```
    canvas {
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: gray;
    vertical-align: top;
        }
```

just add vertical-align: top; to canvas and that fixes it.